# What's wrong with my code to convert farenheight to Celsius?

Tags: python, macos, converters

```
#Programme to covert Farenheight to Celcius
F=input("Enter Value:")

F=((F-32)/9)*5
       print("The temperature is ",F,"Degrees Celcius")
```

When i try to run it it says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `input` returns a `str` you need to cast this to a float in order for this to work

Comment: `F = int(input('..'))`

Comment: That makes sense thank you. I now have it written like this                                  F=int(input("Enter Value:")

Celcius=((F-32)/9)*5
print("The temperature is ",Celcius,"Degrees Celsius") and it now says on the calculation line under celsius 'invalid syntax'?

Comment: You missed a close bracket for the int() for the code in the comments

Comment: ok it works now. thank you everyone

Answer (score 2):

Type cast you input to an int

```
F=int(input("Enter Value:"))
```

And force the division to return a float.
Add this at the very top

```
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with floating point numbers:

```
#Programme to covert Farenheight to Celcius
F = float(input("Enter Value:"))

F = ((F-32.0) / 9.0) * 5.0
print("The temperature is {:.1f} Degrees Celcius".format(F))
```

Giving you:

```
Enter Value:33
The temperature is 0.6 Degrees Celcius
```

The `{:.1f}` tells it to format `F` the floating point result as a string to one decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

```
`F=((float(F)-32)/9)*5`
```

Or

```
F=float(input('Enter value'))
[...]`
```

Input return strings, you have to change them into int or float.